Urgent help with R-LWE Parameters Choice
I am trying to understand CKKS bootstrap algorithm and wanted to understand how is p (plaintext modulo) and q (ciphertext modulo) related in determining the size of the modulus chain. Suppose my ring dimension is 2^16, and security bit is 128 bits, I get a modulus chain of size 32 elements. How is p and q related to the size of the modulo chain? How do I determine what is p and q in the above parameters choice, since I need to run the LWE estimator to understand other parameters choices
